# Highcharts: How to resize chart from external JS?

Tags: dynamic, size, highcharts

I have two charts on a page, their codes stored in different files. What Im trying to achieve is: When I click on first chart, the second should change its size (lower height and width). Function that should do this is in yet another file (but I think it´s not the condition)... I tried to change the width of containing div, but it only cuts the chart. Then I tried to change the width of that div and then to load that chart again...no result.... Is it even possible to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [setSize()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.setSize%28%29) function.

For example:

```
 chart.setSize(newWidth, newHeight);
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it also possible to hide the labels this way or similarly? I tried to add chart.options.plotOptions.series.dataLabels.enabled = false; in the click event, but doesn´t work.

Comment: And also tooltips.... I hope its okay to ask in the comments, I don´t want to make another question just for that...

Comment: This is new feature for Highcharts 3.0, to achieve that use:
chart.series[0].update(options), where in options you can disable dataLabels.

Comment: When Highcharts 3.0 will be available?

Comment: Within a few weeks - right now beta is available: http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-news/53-highcharts-3-0-beta-released